# Applying CSS to GWT MenuBar and adding icon/png with each menu item

Tags: css, gwt

Hi is there a way to apply CSS to GWT menu bar so I would look like Ubuntu menu bar theme?
Also, is there a way to add icon/png with the menu item (but not with CSS).

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is:

Create an HTML with the image and label on it and insert the HTML as text into the MenuItem:

```
public MenuItem(String text, boolean asHTML /*set to true*/, Command cmd){...}
```

Where, 'text' would contain the String representation of the HTML. Easy.

Cheers.